# Combine paginated pdf images into one, continuous image

Tags: pdf, image-processing, pagination

Spouse gets patterns as pdf files. They offer A4 paginated, 24" wide, or 36" wide strips, except that they expect the printer to break up a huge image into strips.

Task #1: Combine separate images (from pdf files) into a 2D grid

Task #2: create new pdf files that are actuality 36" wide (the widest non-speciality plotter size) sections of these large inmates (and they need alignment marks)

I don't even know what to call this type of technology. Most references to "combining pdf" want to add pages to create a multi page document.

All advice is welcome

Cheers

Comment: *a* in which language, using which pdf library do you intend to implement that program? *b* can you share an example pdf?

Comment: No specific language. I can use utilities or an API. I will try and find examples, but think of a Thomas Guide (back when we used paper maps)